# I am trying to use event bus in vue js .But this error repeatedly appears

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

i have two components event1.vue and event2.vue they both are imported to app.vue. i emit a eventbus in evnet2.vue that event is pass to event1.vue.When i click the

tag of event2.vue the title of both of event1.vue and event2.vue need to be changed.but error appears repeteadly

**Error image of console**

[image]

**Event2.vue**

```
   <template>
<div >

     <p v-on:click="ram">{{title}}</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import bus from '../main';
export default {

  data () {
    return {
        title:'jello'
    }
  },
  methods:{
      ram:function(){

          bus.$emit('change','nepal');
      }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
div{
    background:red;
}
</style>
```

**Event1.vue**

```
    <template>
<div>

    <p>{{title}}</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {bus} from '../main';
export default {

  data () {
    return {
      title:'hell'
    }
  },

  created(){
    bus.$on('change', (data) => {
this.title= data;
    }
  )
}
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**main.js**

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import VueRouter from  'vue-router'
import Routes from './routes'

export const bus = new Vue();

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router=new VueRouter({
routes:Routes,
mode:'history'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router:router
})
```

Comment: It would really be nice if you post some sample code for us to see.

Comment: i added a code.Can you review it?

Comment: You can simply use this.$root.$emit(). No need to add a bus